# Parse a Complex Object in XML with Jersey

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jersey-2.0

I am using Jersey and face an issue about how to parse a complex object to xml format, please help me about it, many thanks.
Here is the detail.

First, I make a entity container object like below:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RestResponse {

    //It can be any kinds of type, collection, single object etc
    private Object data;

    //... still have many properties

    public RestResponse() {
    }

    public RestResponse(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

And here is one of my entity class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entity1{

    private String name;

    private Map<String, Object> otherData = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Entity1(){
        this.name = "aaa";
        otherData.put("address", "XXXXX");
        otherData.put("age", 13);   
        //more...

        this.otherData = otherData
    }

    public Entity1(String name, Integer age){
        this.name = "aaa";
        otherData.put("address", "XXXXX");
        otherData.put("age", age);  

        this.otherData = otherData
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getOtherData() {
        return otherData;
    }
}
```

Here is my resource class:

```
@Path("/test")
public class EntityResource{

    @GET
    @Path("test1")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response test1() {
        Entity1 entity = new Entity1();
        return Response.ok(new RestResponse(entity)).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("test2")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public Response test2() {   
            List entities = new ArrayList<Entity1>();
            entities.add(new Entity1("E1"));
            entities.add(new Entity1("E2"));

            return Response.ok(new RestResponse(entities)).build();
    }
}
```

Configure jersey with above code, it works fine when I require json format response, but for xml format response, I always get 500 error, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found the solution, the answer is simple, I register  **JacksonXMLProvider.class** as a XML provider, hope this can help other people.